# Excel VSTO document specialization can't load dependent DLL

Tags: deployment, vsto

I have an Excel 2007 document customization assembly that's dependent on another managed assembly (DLL 'A') which in turn is dependent on an unmanaged, native DLL written in C++ (DLL 'B').  I have created a Windows installer project to deploy the customization assembly, its deployment and application manifests, the dependent assembly (A) and the native DLL (B) into "Program Files\" directory, while the Excel document (a template actually) is copied into the user's "My Documents" folder.  The template's _AssemblyLocation property has been modified accordingly to find the deployment manifest.

The template fails to load.  Looking at the loading sequence in Process Monitor it is clear the Excel template sucessfully loads the customization DLL which finds and loads DLL 'A', but A then fails to find DLL 'B' even though B is in the same directory.  Process Monitor shows A looking for B in all the directories listed in the PATH environment variable, but not in its own directory.

What is the convention when searching for dependent assemblies/DLL's in a VSTO document customization solution?  Is there a way to help A find B without adding the application directory to the PATH?